# After deploy my MVC app to Azure content not displaying

Tags: c#, azure

Like in title. I create app C# MVC.

1. In local work properly
2. In Azure not displaying full content: there is the link https://scheduler20200527200904.azurewebsites.net/
   When I hit F12 there in debuger there is error

   > TypeError: scheduler.createUnitsView is not a function
   >   scheduler20200527200904.azurewebsites.net:89:27
   >   init https://scheduler20200527200904.azurewebsites.net/:89
   >   onload https://scheduler20200527200904.azurewebsites.net/:1

And This

```
> Loading failed for item „script” from „https://scheduler20200527200904.azurewebsites.net/Scripts/ext/dhtmlxscheduler_units.js”. scheduler20200527200904.azurewebsites.net:8:1

> Loading failed for item „script” from „https://scheduler20200527200904.azurewebsites.net/Scripts/ext/dhtmlxscheduler_week_agenda.js”.
```

How to add them? I have it in my local repository.

Comment: None of your `/ext` scripts are there. How are you deploying this?

Comment: Using publish option in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Haha i just repair it xD
So for the future 
Look 
If you I have issues after deploy app to Azure hit on your site F12 and check debug
There should be a hint what is going wrong.
For me I just use console there go to scripts catalog. Add a catalog ext and using cloud explorer I uploaded a two missing files. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

So for the future 
Look 
If you like I have issues after deploy app to Azure hit on your site F12 and check debug.
There should be a hint what is going wrong.
For me I just use console on Azure site there I go to scripts catalog. Add a catalog ext and using cloud explorer I uploaded a two missing files. That is all.